# The Kernel of the homomorphism for the units in the p-adic numbers?

Tags: group-theory, p-adic-number-theory

In Seer's "A Course in Arithmetic" he states:

> Let $U = \Bbb Z_p^*$ be the group of $p$-adic units. We define a homomorphism $\epsilon_n : U \rightarrow (\Bbb Z/p^n \Bbb Z)^*$. Then the $U_n = 1 + p^n \Bbb Z_p$, and this is the kernel of the homomorphism.

My question is why is this the kernel?

I have tried visualizing $\epsilon_n$ as a truncation but I still can't get it.

As a sideline question could someone please confirm for me that EVERY $p$-adic integer is also a unit? I couldn't find a clear answer online.

Comment: How did you define $\epsilon_n$ and the $p$-adics, $\mathbb Z_p$?

Comment: And no, not every $p$-adic integer is a unit. $p$, for example, has no inverse in $\mathbb Z_p$. (It has an inverse in $\mathbb Q_p$, but the definition of unit of a ring is having an inverse in the ring. (And, of course, zero never has an inverse in a ring.)

Comment: Hi Thomas, really appreciate your reply, thank you for that.

$\epsilon_n$ is the truncation of $Z_n$ at $a_(n-1)$

I have no idea why this bracket is not closing, sorry about that. It reads as expected; a_(n-1)

Ah its true, I think because Seer introduced the group of units without much additional notation it lead to some confusion the distinction between the units and $Z_p^*$